# How long is the training to get a Boeing 777 rating if one has a 737-200 rating?

Tags: boeing-737, boeing-777, type-ratings

I was wondering if anyone knows how long the training for a 777 takes if one already holds a 737-200 rating.
I've looked it up online and didn't find an adequate answer.
According to [this site](https://www.panamacademy.com/boeing-777-type-rating-and-training-courses), the course for 777 PIC initial certification takes 21 days (48 h) and the course for 777 PIC recurrent certification takes 4 days (16 h), but there's no mention of anything regarding previous ratings.
[Here](http://www.pprune.org/archive/index.php/t-559078.html), someone says they think that to go from the 737NG to the 777 would only take 3/4 sim sessions, and someone else says that the course to go from 737NG to 777 is shorter than the course to go from 737-200 to 777.

Does anyone know how many days the "conversion" course would take?

Am I correct to assume one doesn't have to take the full 777 initial certification course if one holds a current 737-200 rating?

And what if the 737-200 rating is no longer valid... does one have to take the full 777 initial certification course?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

A flight school can offer an "abbreviated type rating course" which takes into account skills from previous type ratings, assuming you have flown an adequate number of flight hours on those ratings.

Boeing also offers a shortened type rating course, details are halfway down their [page](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/services/flight-operations-solutions/training-and-resourcing/flight-training.page). To answer your question, Boeing [claims 13-15 days](http://www.boeing.com/assets/pdf/commercial/aviationservices/brochures/ShortenedTypeRatingCourse.pdf) for their training and requires 1,000 hours of experience, but it does not depend on a specific rating. There is an even shorter 777-787 conversion as well, that requires a 777 rating.

I think their assumption is that they can skip a lot of basic handling, CRM, checklist type training and focus on the technical aspects. A training provider with the proper approvals could offer a similar class.

Also, for reference, there is the Airbus A320-A330-A340-A380 conversion training which uses the proprietary term "cross crew qualification", and takes less than 2 weeks versus 6 for a full rating. This is done under a [EASA approved syllabus](https://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/Airbus%20Family%20CCQMMF%20JOEB%20Report%20%28120304%29.pdf), which allows you to do it at any [qualified school](https://www.lufthansa-flight-training.com/documents/10156/5537743/Cross+Crew+Qualification+Course+%28CCQ%29). Here the requirements are 150 FH on the appropriate Airbus type, and 3 months of experience.

Comment: That across the Airbus family with a high degree of commonality. The only commonality between B737-200 and B777 is the name on the bonnet and the number of wings.

Comment: @Koyovis The steam gauge 737 isn't even common to the NG: Boeing says that's a 2 week class. 737NG to 777 is much more common. Similarly, the A300/A310 is in its own world, which even had 3 incompatible variants: the 3 crew analog, the FFCC 2 crew analog, and the EFIS model.

Comment: Indeed, exactly my point. It would seem to me that the complete initial B777 type rating course would need to be done, since there is almost zero commonality.

Comment: @Koyovis I see your point. Boeing's advertising doesn't specifically call out EFIS or a type particular rating, though I do think they may be making certain optimistic assumptions. Still, basic handling and crew coordination  skills still carry over.

Comment: Thank you for the links. That  Boeing link was actually really good (though I didn't find that specific conversion mentioned -- is it under a different name?). As I don't know what the two types of aircraft have in common  (or what they have in common with other aircraft), I cannot assess whether one would need a shortened course or a full one, but    knowing that the shortened course takes 2 weeks (and the full one takes 3) is helpful because now I know more or less how long it'd take. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: is the 1000 hours of experience related to the Boeing family? Or could someone with 1000 hours on a Cessna, complete the 777 course in 15 days?

Answer (score 1):

The intital or recurrent type ratings for a jet are a predetermined duration set by the school, regardless of any previous type ratings a student holds.  However the student will probably digest the material much quicker if the possess a type rating in an aircraft similar in size, features, systems, and performance, or I’d the new aircraft come from the same manufacturer, to the one they are currently seeking a type rating for.